# Store the Logged in Users's Country in the DataBase

Tags: 7

How could I store the country of the registered user, when he/she logs in. I am hoping I could store it in the DB to later retrieve it within the reports.

I am using Drupal 7.

Many Many Thanks.

Comment: First things first - how are you planning to determine what country the user is visiting from? Secondly, have you heard of [Google Analytics](http://www.google.co.uk/analytics/)?

Comment: I guess, it would be done through IP, right. I am hoping of some way, that when a user logs in the site, his country is stored in the database through his IP. So a row with his User ID, country and date/time he/she logged in. We have a in-house, customized reporting framework within which we want to add this functionality.Thanks

Comment: Ok, I have been searching within Tables, and found that one of the tables have been saving IP for each logged in user. I guess, now I have to show the country against it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there's a pre-built solution for just that: [ip2country](https://drupal.org/project/ip2country)

> This module uses a visitor's IP address to identify the geographical location (country) of the user. The module makes this determination and stores the result as an ISO 3166 2-character country code in the Drupal $user object, but otherwise has no effect on the operation of your site. The intent is simply to provide the information for use by other modules. A function is also provided for you to perform your own lookup, to use in your own manner. Features include automatic updates of the IP-country database and admin spoofing of an arbitrary IP or Country for testing purposes.

Comment: The problem is that it isn't working :( for Drupal 7. Upon seeing notes, I am using this:- $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
       echo ip2country_get_country($ip); and it just shows empty string.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/ip2country?categories=bug) it should work fine. If it doesn't, you need to post a bug report there; but make sure you've followed the installation instructions to the letter before doing so. I haven't read them all but they look fairly involved. Check, check and double check :)